# Fazer gráfico trabalhar com linhas ao invés de colunas Google Charts

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-charts

Estou fazendo uma página com um gráfico de avaliações de serviço usando o ***google charts***, consegui que o mesmo pegasse as informações do banco de dados usando colunas como referencia e funcionou perfeitamente! Porém preciso funcione diferente, ao invés de usar os valores das colunas, ele tem que contar o número de linhas e ai sim dar a porcentagem, para ficar mais claro aqui está uma breve amostra de como é a estrutura de banco que estou usando!

[Tabela que fiz para teste e está funcionando](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jpuf.png)

[Tabela que preciso utilizar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOg3J.png)

Aqui está o código que estou usando para fazer da forma tradicional:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          <?php

                while($chart = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                  echo "['".$chart['avaliacao']."', ".$chart['qntd']."],";
                }

          ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Jantar',
          pieHole: 0.4,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="donutchart" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
```

Espero que tenham entendido minha dúvida, se precisarem de mais informações estou a disposição!

Answer (score -2):

Consegui arrumar, é só colocar

```
SELECT avaliacao, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY avaliacao;
```

No lugar do *SELECT* padrão que ele soma as linhas e insere no gráfico :)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).